# Installing private dependencies via npm in a VS Team Services CI build

Tags: node.js, npm, azure-devops

I'm setting up some CI builds of NodeJS projects in VS Team Services.  I currently have four projects being cloned from private Github repositories, running `npm install`, and running unit tests.  Because I'm giving the VS Team Services build an access token for the repositories it's cloning, these builds all pass.

The fifth project relies on one of the other four projects as a dependency in `package.json`.  The build for this project fails on `npm install` when attempting to clone the private repository because the build does not have permission to clone the repository.  How can I give this build access to clone our private repositories during `npm install`?

I have one build definition for each of the five projects, and each project is a separate repository in `my-org` on Github.  In each build definition, the connection to Github is managed by personal access token, and the repository points to `my-org/project-name`.  The `package.json` file of the project in the fifth, failing, build has a `dependencies` configuration that looks like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "project-name": "git+ssh://git@github.com/my-org/project-name.git#master",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "react": "^15.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.1"
  }
```

The first image shows the `npm install` step of my build definition.
[image: npm install build step]

The second image shows the `npm test` step of my build definition.
[image: npm test build step]

Comment: can you add more details? do you have one build defintion? how those Git repositories are related? how does the package.json files looks like?

Comment: @LucaCappa I've added some details per your request.  Thanks for replying, and I hope my additions clarify my issue for you.

Comment: Can you show your build definition?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT Thanks for your reply.  I've added a couple screenshots of the build definition.  Again, I hope they're helpful.  Again, the `npm install` step is failing because the proper permissions to clone the private repository don't exist.

Comment: @chazzlabs what's the build log if you change projectname as `"git+ssh://git@github.com:my-org/project-name.git#master"` or `"git+https://github.com/my-org/project-name.git#master"` in dependencies?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT Changing the dependency to ```git+ssh://git@github.com:my-org/project-name.git#master``` resulted in this error:

```Host key verification failed. Could not read from remote repository.```

  Changing to ```git+https://github.com/my-org/project-name.git#master``` gave this error:

```Invalid username or password. Authentication failed for 'https://git@github.com/my-org/my-project.git/'```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the build agent will not able to authenticate because of lack of SSH keys on the build agent and because the host verification will fail anyway.

Instead you should create a [Personal Access Token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) on GitHub with 'repo' **only** scope, then you should use it on your packages.json file (notice that `ssh` is replaced with `https` protocol):

```
"project-name": "git+https://<user>:<token>@github.com/my-org/project-name.git#master",
```

Comment: Luca, thanks for your answer.  This seems like the only solution but unfortunately doesn't seem to fit our current workflow.  The token could be injected into our builds as an environment variable, but this would presumably cause problems for our developers, as npm wouldn't be able to pull from our private repositories without the environment variable set on each developer's machine.

Comment: Luca, I've accepted your answer because it seems like the proper solution to my question.  As I mentioned in the previous comment, it unfortunately doesn't solve my issue.  Thanks again for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Recently i needed to do this in Azure Devops on a **Windows based agent**,  Instead of changing dependencies to include user and token in the packages.json, it was easier to create a build step to add the authentication information from environment variables to windows credentials store and instructing git to use that.

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
cmdkey /generic:LegacyGeneric:target=git:https://our-private-domain.com /user:git-readonly-use@our-private-domain.com /pass:"Personal Access Token With Read Permissions"
```

After adding these configurations, Npm installs that we were doing using a script in source code went through without any issue

```
"dependencies": {
"example-1": "git+https://our-private-domain.com/proj/example-1.git#v0.1.9",
"example-2": "git+https://our-private-domain.com/proj/example-2.git#master"
}
```